# UIView frame not updated during traitCollectionDidChange

Tags: ios, swift, frame, calayer, uitraitcollection

I did some drawing using CALayer based on the frame in my subclass of UIView, I need to update the lines when the device rotate but in traitCollectionDidChange, the frame is still holding the value before the rotation. Is there a way to get the updated values of the frame after the rotation?

My drawing codes looks like this, called in traitCollectionDidChange of it's view controller:

```
func setup() {

    layer.sublayers?.removeAll()

    let xAxisLine = UIBezierPath()
    xAxisLine.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: frame.height))
    xAxisLine.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: frame.height))
    let xAxisLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    xAxisLayer.path = xAxisLine.cgPath
    xAxisLayer.lineWidth = 2
    xAxisLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    xAxisLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer.addSublayer(xAxisLayer)
}
```

This part draws the X-Axis of my custom graph but more importantly the frame values are that of before the rotation thus the entire graph is out of place and size.

From the view controller, I called it by:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {

    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

    barView.setup()
}
```

Comment: Please update the question with your `traitCollectionDidChange` implementation.

Comment: I'd admit that I should not use my setup codes for redraw but currently my focus is on obtaining the new values of the frame for redrawing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You doesn't update your drawing you always add a new layer to your view when orientation changes.

You should create the layer in `viewDidLoad` and save a reference to it. In `traitCollectionDidChange` you just assign a new path to the layer.

Comment: but without the new height and width of the view how do i calculate the path to draw?

Comment: Instead of `traitCollectionDidChange`you can use overwrite `layoutSubviews` (`UIView`) or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (`UIViewController`).

Answer (score 0):

you can use motion event it is help full for detect devices in ios.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW2

Comment: Thanks... but I do not need that much accuracy in the device rotation. I only require the frame of the UIView after the rotation. Which I allow the device to perform by its own calculation